# Call C# DLL API from python

Tags: python, c#, python.net

I got some C# DLL file with methods inside it and I'm trying to use it from python:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"C:\Users\ssandler\Documents\Python_projects\CLR_TEST")
import clr
clr.AddReference(r"C:\Users\ssandler\Documents\Python_projects\CLR_TEST\CAPLIB.DLL")
from CAPLIB import  CapLib
cl = CapLib()
cl.CAP_ClearCsrRegister()
```

but get the folowing error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/ssandler/Documents/Python_projects/CLR_TEST/test.py", line 14, in 
cl.CAP_ClearCsrRegister()
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at CAPLIB.CapLib.CAP_ClearCsrRegister()

this method exists in that class:
[.NET reflector capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GRiX.png)

Any ideas?